# ASP.Net load balancing

Tags: asp.net, load-balancing

I am working on asp.net (newbie) and I am trying to understand what it means to do "load balancing" for the web site.  The website will be used by multiple users and resources (database, web service,..).

If anyone could help me understanding the concept of the load balance for asp.net web site, I would really appreciate it.
Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

One load-balancing-related issue you may want to be aware of at development time: where you store your session state.  [This MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972429.aspx) gives a good overview of your options.

If you implement your asp.net system using "out-of-process" or "sql-server-mode" session state management, that will give you some additional flexibliity later, if you decide to introduce a load-balancer to your deployed system:

1. Your load balancer needn't handle session affinity.  As one poster mentioned above, all modern load-balancers handle it anyway, so this is a minor consideration in any case.
2. Web-gardens (a sort of IIS/server-implemented load-balancer) REQUIRES use of "out-of-process" or "sql-server-mode" session state management.  So if your system is already configured that way, you'll be one step closer to being able to use web-gardens.

Answer (score 1):

**What is it?**
Load balancing simply refers to distributing a workload between two or more computers.  As a concept, it's not unique to asp.net.  Although having separate machines for your database and web server could be called "load balancing" it more commonly refers to using multiple machines to serve a single role, such as having multiple web servers.

**Should you worry about it?** Probably not.  Do you already have a performance problem?  Are your database and web server on their own machines?  If you do find that your server resources are strained, it would probably be easier to scale up (a more powerful single machine) than out (load balancing). These days, a dedicated box can handle a LOT of traffic if your code is decent.

Comment: One thing to think about for the "should you worry about it?" question: if you are building websites for clients, it's always good to understand these things. I've been bitten in the past by having a client decide to host a site on multiple load-balanced webservers, when it had never been developed with that in mind. If you don't control the hosting environment yourself, it's great to understand all the possibilities.

Comment: That's true.  But if the client has a self-professed newbie trying to tackle something with those kind of possibilities, things aren't likely to end well regardless of whether he tries to plan for load balancing or not.  Being able to anticipate that kind of thing and execute well is no simple matter.

Answer (score 0):

Load Balancing, in the programming sense, does not apply to ASP.NET; it applies to a technique to try to distribute server load across two or more machines, rather than it all being used on one machine.  Unless you will have many thousands (millions?) of users, you probably do not need to worry about it.

Check the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load_balancing_(computing)) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Load balancing is not specific for any on technology stack be it asp.net, jsp etc.  To load balance is to spread the incoming requests to a web site over more than one server.  This is typically done with a software or hardware load balancer.  The load balancer sits in front of two or more web servers and delegates the incoming traffic. Although this technique is not limited to web servers.  [Load Balancing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load_balancing_(computing))

Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

I've never used it, but an option is IIS [Application Request Routing](http://www.iis.net/download/applicationrequestrouting).

> IIS Application Request Routing (ARR)
>   2.0 enables Web server administrators, hosting providers, and Content
>   Delivery Networks (CDNs) to increase
>   Web application scalability and
>   reliability through rule-based
>   routing, client and host name
>   affinity, load balancing of HTTP
>   server requests, and distributed disk
>   caching

Answer (score 0):

In a typical web server/database scenario, the db is almost always guaranteed to load up the machine first. This is because dealing with storing data requires more resources. Before you even start looking at load balancing your web server, you need to think about how to load balance the database.

Spreading one database across multiple servers is a lot harder than load balancing a web server. One of the techniques that can be used is [sharding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shard_(database_architecture)) (or horizontal partitioning). This is where some records are stored on one server, and other records - on another server.  For example records with ID 1-900000 are on server 1 and records 900001- are on server 2.

In comparison to DB load balancing, spreading the load across multiple ASP.NET servers is not overly complicated. Most of the session issues can be easily mitigated by using out of process session and/or never talking to `Application.Cache` directly. Data load balancing on the other hand is hard and requires a lot of planning and trial and error. In most cases, talking to a load balanced DB requires using an ORM which supports it (e.g. NHibernate) or your own Data Access Layer. The reason being is that you need to take out establishing a connection from the code that uses the database, so that the decision which DB to talk to is handled in one place.

Answer (score 0):

the exact solution is to save session into the SQL Server with Stored Procedure. To read session  call 'SessionCheck' stored Procedure.

Answer (score -2):

I'd add that it really isn't something to worry about. By the time you need a load balancer, you can probably afford one of the neato newfangled ones with sticky sessions so you don't even have to deal with the session boogeyman.